# EE2.2.0 | sort="asc" only shows 2 entries where sort="desc" shows all

Tags: channel-entries, sort

There is a page with 6 entries that are supposed to show but only shows 2 when sorted in ascending order.  I sort in descending order and all 6 entries show.  What is going on here?

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="gcswim-meets"
    orderby="gym-date" 
    sort="asc"}

    {if '{gym-date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}' >= '{current_time format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}'}

    <tr>
        <td width="220">
            {title}
        </td>
        <td width="68">
            {gym-date format="%m/%j"}
        </td>
        <td width="68">
            {gym-time}
        </td>
        <td> 
            {gym-location}
        </td>
    </tr>

    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out there is a secret limit of 100 for entries.  Adding limit="900" fixed it.  This is pretty ridiculous, I have to say.

Comment: To be fair a no-limit by default would be madness and lead to more issues. It's well documented though.

Comment: Yeah later in the day I thought about it and realized a limit makes a lot of sense, I just wish it was somehow more apparent that it is there.

Comment: To be fair, it is not "secret" - [it's right in the docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/channel/channel_entries.html#limit).